# Declaring an array with a non-constant size variable

Tags: c, arrays

I'm studying for my test in C and I'm reading in a C summary I downloaded from some site.
It is written that it is not allowed to write `arr[i]` where `i` is a variable. The only way to do it is with malloc.
However, I wrote the following code and it compiles without warnings and without error on valgrind:

```
int index = 5;
int a4[index];

a4[0] = 1;
a4[1] = 2;

int index2;
scanf("%d",&index2);
int a5[index2];
a5[0] = 1;
a5[1] = 2;
```

So what is the truth behind array declarations?
thank you!

Comment: As a warning: I would recommend not trusting summaries of C found on the Internet too much; I recently spent a lot of time reviewing C and C++ in preparation for interviews, and found that most of the Internet "study guides" had inaccurate or misleading information in them.  I'd recommend [a good introductory book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), with the caveat that often such books don't cover C99 features because they are less commonly implemented.

Comment: While they're legal in C99, VLAs are *extremely* dangerous unless you already have a very small bound on the value of the expression to be used as the array size. They can easily lead to stack overflow (not the good kind :-) and clobbering of heap memory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

C99 allows [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) to be created on the stack.  Your compiler may support this feature.  This features is not available in C89.

What the summary told you was true, from a certain point of view.  :-)

Comment: The variable length array makes me feel confused at first because I remember it's not supported when I used to learn C using VC6.0. Just now I find it is used on the example code of InsertionSort on Hackerrank.com. Now it's clear. Hackerrank adopts gcc4.7.3,C99 Mode, so this feature is totally supported.