# c syntax: array

Tags: c, syntax

For `char[size]`, is it true that `size` must be `constant`?

Or say,will it work ?

```
int length;
...

char[length] arr;
```

Sorry,don't have the environment here so can't try it myself.

Comment: This only works in C99. So you should be fine unless you're stuck with an obsolete compiler, e.g. MSVC.

Comment: Duplicate of [Declaring an array with a non-constant size variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814719/declaring-an-array-with-a-non-constant-size-variable) and others (there may be a better duplicate question; that's just one I had at hand)

Comment: If it works in C99,what's different from `malloc` ?

Comment: It's `char arr[length]` not `char[length] arr`.

Comment: So that's the essential difference between heap and stack,right?

Comment: the lifetime of VLA ends when its scope ends. not when function returns...

Comment: @Nyan,so this is the most significant difference between stack and heap,right?

Answer (score 1):

Pre C99, yes; the size of an array must be a constant integral expression. C99, however, adds Variable Length Arrays (VLA's), which allow an array to have a dynamic size.

Comment: If it works in C99,what's different from `malloc` ?Or say,what's different between heap and stack for C99?