# Scope of constant and char arrays

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Declaring an array with a non-constant size variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814719/declaring-an-array-with-a-non-constant-size-variable)

This is my code:

```
const int xsize=150;
char Hey[xsize];
```

I don't understand why I cannot declare my new array Hey using the constant above.
Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not valid C89 code. You can't declare an array with variable size, even if the variable happens to be `const`.

It would work if you had it as a `#define` rather than a `const int`. It is valid in C99, though. GCC and other compilers also offer it as an extension in C89 mode.

Comment: GCC allows it in C++ as a language extension with `-std=gnu++98` (the default.. or is it still?) or with `-std=gnu++11`.

Comment: Note: It is only valid C99 in block scope, at file scope, you still need a _constant expression_ for the size.

Answer (score 1):

Because `const` does not create a constant. It creates a read-only object.

The difference between object and constant is that objects have a specific memory location they live at; constants live only in source code.

Answer (score 1):

In C89, an array size should be a constant expression. A `const` variable is not a constant expression. To do this, you have to use rather VLA, from C99.